# Find specific character string from log file

Tags: python, string

I need to find a specific character string if it exists in a line. The follow is an sample log file content.

```
Thu 04/19/2018    22:37:58.51    EV_MIO_IDC_WW1815 
Thu 04/19/2018    22:11:26.69    ATV_1816_CNL
```

If string with prefix "ATV" is found in the 2nd line, then return the whole string as "ATV_1816_CNL".

Comment: With no attempt posted, you get neg points. Try regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is specific to your case, you need to provide a more general question.

```
import re

myStr = "Thu 04/19/2018 22:37:58.51 EV_MIO_IDC_WW1815 Thu 04/19/2018 22:11:26.69 ATV_1816_CNL"

print(re.search('ATV\w{9}', myStr).group())

# ATV_1816_CNL
```

Comment: the file not include only 2 lines. it was an example. it could including 2000 lines too

Comment: in addition - i need to search the last line i look for (by date - newest upper)

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you exactly want.